# Center text vertically in v-chip

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How can I center the text inside a v-chip component vertically?
Since it's a vuetify component, I looked at the documentation but there's no such property for this.

```
<v-chip
   v-if="this.drawerNodeData.type == 'Telecom'"
   :color="telecom"
   text-color="white"
   class="chips"
>
   {{ this.drawerNodeData.type }}
</v-chip>
```

[image: Here's how it looks]

Comment: How does it look?

Comment: It looks centered horizontally but vertically closer to the bottom. (don't know how to add a picture in a reply to show you though)

Comment: what are the css properties applied to the `chips` class?

Comment: it's still empty I was planning on filling it later actually

Comment: the content of a chip is by default centered, I think you're adding some style that affects this element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said styles for chips class are not yet implemented. In that case your code should work as per the requirement as by default chip text center aligned vertically and horizontally. Here is the demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.1/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-chip color="primary" text-color="white">Default</v-chip>
    </v-container>  
  </v-app>
</div>
```